# Is it possible to piggyback off of an ADFS 3.0 login using machinekey?

Tags: asp.net, wif, adfs

I have three asp.net applications.  Only one of them has a forms authentication login.  I redirect anonymous users to that one login page for all three applications to login.  Once they log in, they automatically redirected back to the application and page they were attempting to access.

I enabled this functionality by setting the same MachineKey in all three applications.

Is there a way to do this for ADFS 3.0 WIF authentication as well?  It doesn't seem to work the same in my testing.  When I log into the application that is wired up to ADFS, I still can't access the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIF and ADFS don't work the same way as traditional forms authentication.  These technologies rely on issuing access tokens, and require that dependent applications (also known as Relying Parties, or RPs) configure a trust relationship with the token provider (AKA Identity Provider, or IP).  You can't share the cookie with MachineKey between apps that have not directly authenticated with an IP, and to be quite honest you don't want to.

The typical web scenario (also known as **Passive Federation**) is to have a separate application that functions as a Security Token Service (STS).  This application houses the Login.aspx page and is protected with Forms or Windows Authentication like you would find in a classic ASP.NET scenario.  When you attempt to access a web application that requires authentication, it needs to be set up to redirect you to the STS website, rather than handling it by itself.  Once you log into the central STS, it will issue you a token that you then provide to applications to gain access.  If you use WIF properly, this is all handled behind the scenes and is just a matter of configuration.

Each of your three web applications should be configured with a trust relationship to your IP.  You said that you have a web application wired up to ADFS already, if that's via the proper trust relationship, then you should simply have to replicate that set up to your other 2 applications.